# turning json type column into R dataframe

Tags: r, json, dataframe, text-mining

Here I have a dataframe `df1` that I would like to turn into a dataframe `df2`. Does anybody have any suggestions/ideas?

```
df1 <- data.frame (ID  = c("UniqueValue1", "UniqueValue2", "UniqueValue3",
                          "UniqueValue4", "UniqueValue5", "UniqueValue6"),
                  stringtext = c("Factor1:1.0, Factor2:2.0, Factor3:3.0"))
```

into...

```
df2 <- data.frame (ID  = c("UniqueValue1", "UniqueValue2", "UniqueValue3",
                          "UniqueValue4", "UniqueValue5", "UniqueValue6"),
                  Factor1 = c("1.0", "1.0", "1.0", "1.0", "1.0", "1.0"),
                  Factor2 = c("2.0", "2.0", "2.0", "2.0", "2.0", "2.0"),
                  Factor3 = c("3.0", "3.0", "3.0", "3.0", "3.0", "3.0"))
```

Is there a way where you don't have to manually specify 'Factor1', 'Factor2', and 'Factor3'? Like if whatever is behind the colon, turn that into a column, and what ever is AFTER the colon, turn that into its specific value. If we can get that, that would be awesome. Any help or feedback regarding this would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, it may not be very elegant but gets the outcome you want.

```
column_names <- as.data.frame(unlist(str_split(df1$stringtext,","))) %>%
setNames(c("factor")) %>%
distinct() %>%
mutate(factor = trimws(factor)) %>%
mutate(factor = gsub(":.+$","",factor))

df1 <- df1 %>%
tidyr::separate(stringtext, column_names$factor ,sep=",")

df <- as.data.frame((sapply(df1,function(x) gsub("^F.+:","",trimws(x)))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way where you don't have to manually specify 'Factor1', 'Factor2', and 'Factor3'? Like if whatever is behind the colon, turn that into a column, and what ever is AFTER the colon, turn that into its specific value.

If we can get that, that would be awesome. Thanks so much for your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have json string in a column then you can try one thing -
`map_dfr` is from `purrr` package and `fromJSON` is from `jsonlite`.

```
df <- map_dfr(df$ColumnWithJsonString, fromJSON)
```

This will convert the string to multiple columns.

Let me know if that's helpful
Thanks!